# Win8 won't open after instaling Lubuntu 14.04; infinite loop in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, lubuntu, windows-8

On my HP laptop with windows 8, I installed Lubuntu as a dual boot from a live CD.  At first, I could only access grub through hitting F9-ubuntu, so I tried Boot Repair to no avail.  Then I tried manually loading grub's MBR file where Windows' was, but it didn't help.  I tried turning off secure boot in the BIOS (UEFI), and it opened GRUB straight away.  However, when I try to open the windows option, it flashes black and the same menu comes up, no matter how many times I hit it.  When I turn secure boot back on, it repairs Win8 and I can boot into it until I turn it off again.

I have tried fixing grub, fixing the BCD from the Windows side through recovery and through third party apps, and tried every permutation of all this at least once.  All I want is for my computer to open grub, give me a choice between Lubuntu and windows, and boot the one I ask for.  This is a last ditch effort; I've been working on this about 12 hours straight to no avail.  If anybody can help, I would really, really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Post link to BootInfo report from Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very common problem ..
**In fact**, if you had Lubuntu already installed, and **then** installed Windows 8, that'd render Lubuntu unbootable!
I'll provide solution for both cases, though ..

#### For Windows after Ubuntu:

> You simply need to re-download the ubuntu image *or use the one you've downloaded if you haven't deleted it like you'd probably do ..*
>   Then you have to [boot to ubuntu using a flash drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) ..
>   From there, [fix grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal) ..

#### For Ubuntu after Windows:

> You can do [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2_from_a_Working_System) from Ubuntu first, just to make sure you tried ..
>   You have to use the rescue disk *or the installation disk using the repair option ..*
>   Then, [repair bcd and bootloader from commandline](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en-us) ..
>   You're done !

Comment: Windows came pre-installed, and then I installed Ubuntu.  I already tried repairing bcd and bootloader like it said, and it didn't fix it.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't format the Windows partition by mistake when installing Ubuntu ?

Comment: BootRepair:
"
An error occurred during the repair.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7786954

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com
You can now reboot your computer.

The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair].